# Spring remember me not working with custom filter and java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using a custom Authentication Filter to capture an additional login parameter in a spring mvc application. I want to enable rememeber me feature and i am using java configuration. But remember me feature is not working. If user checks the 'Remember Me' checkbox on the login page i can see that a new entry is added to the persistent_logins table. But once session times out and user clicks on any application link he/she is being re-directed to the login page. Please find relevant code below,

CustomAuthenticationFilter.java:-

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        final Long locationId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("locations"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("LOCATION_ID", locationId);

        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response); 
    } 
}
```

SecurityConfig.java:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=com.test.web.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    AccessDeniedExceptionHandler accessDeniedExceptionHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/secured/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedExceptionHandler);

        http.addFilterBefore(customAuthenticationFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() {
        AuthenticationManager manager = null;
        try {
            manager = super.authenticationManagerBean();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return manager;
    }


    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        handler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        handler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error");
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter () {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter filter= new  CustomAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","POST"));
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        filter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        filter.setRememberMeServices(persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices());
        return filter;
    }


    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices service = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember_me_key", userDetailsService, persistentTokenRepository());
        service.setCookieName("remember_me");
        service.setTokenValiditySeconds(864000);
        return service;
    }

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepositoryImpl;
    }
}
```

I will be really thankful if someone can point me in right direction.

**UPDATE:-**

After clicking on any application link on session expire i am seeing following output in the log. From the log it seems RememberMeAuthenticationFilter is not getting fired.

```
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:136 - No HttpSession currently exists
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:90 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:129 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@36fb061c
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CustomAuthenticationFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:102 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG SessionManagementFilter:92 - Requested session ID 87ABB37D528FC51FFC5C47A717813C79 is invalid.
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/resources/**'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/error/**'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/secured/**'
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:194 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [authenticated]
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:310 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@732b4495, returned: -1
2016-02-22 19:22:12 TRACE AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:331 - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /]
2016-02-22 19:22:12 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:165 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

**UPDATE 2:-**

After adding rememberMe() call the RememberMeAuthenticationFilter is getting called but still remember-me functionality is not working with same behavior as earlier. The latest log is,

```
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:136 - No HttpSession currently exists
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:90 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:129 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1c6103c2
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CustomAuthenticationFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:127 - Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:102 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG SessionManagementFilter:92 - Requested session ID 0C8F3CE7D018DA453CDD9E23A8125212 is invalid.
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - / at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/resources/**'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/error/**'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/secured/**'
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:194 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [authenticated]
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:310 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3c682cd2, returned: -1
2016-02-22 20:00:08 TRACE AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:331 - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /]
2016-02-22 20:00:08 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:165 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Comment: What does logging say - you should get a list of all the filters and see if rememberme is included, or logging

Comment: Hello Farrellmr, yes it seems that RememberMeAuthenticationFilter is not getting fired. I am not sure why. I have added an update above to include a log excerpts. Thanks

Comment: RememberMeAuthenticationFilter is not getting fired may be because i am using a custom authentication filter? And i need to explicitly set RememberMeAuthenticationFilter on the custom authentication filter? But i am not sure how. I have checked UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter api but can't find a way

Answer (score 1):

It looks like remember is not enabled in configure();
see example at

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#rememberMe()

you need to do

```
.formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeServices(persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices());
```

Comment: Hello Bhushan, i added rememberMe() call as per your suggestion but remember me feature is still not working. But with this change RememberMeAuthenticationFilter is getting called as evident from the log. Please see my UPDATE 2. Thanks

Comment: please check  rememberMeServices.autoLogin(request,  response);  May be returning null object. You need to set remember me service to remember me filter as well.

Comment: Bhushan, yes. after adding '.rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())' part spring is now recognizing that it's a remember-me user and is trying to get the user by username from database. And here lies my problem. As mentioned in OP i am using an additional 'location' parameter to authenticate the user. During normal login i am capturing location along with username and pwd and using it in 'loadUserByUsername' function. Now if it's a remember-me user spring calls 'loadUserByUsername' by passing it just a username. And in this case 'location' won't be available and query fails.

Comment: Logically usernames are unique and they can be fetch independent of location.  Method 'loadUserByUsername' will return 'UserDetails' object which will be used by spring security and it is spring defined object. I am not finding any good use of location to create 'UserDetails' object. If you still need that you can keep application level map(kind of cache) username map to location.

Comment: In my case, an user can be assigned to one or more locations while user creation. He/she will be able to choose the location while login and only the data specific to that location will be shown to user. So it is necessary for me to store location in DB, capture it during login, and use it in authentication. Application level map may not be an option because locations can be added dynamically.

Comment: FYI i added a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570818/spring-remember-me-with-extra-login-parameter related to using extra login parameter with remember-me