# Spring remember-me with extra login parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In a spring mvc application i am capturing an additional 'location' parameter on login screen and using it for authentication in addition to username. So in 'loadUserByUsername' my sql query is something like,

```
select from user where username = ? and location = ?
```

Now, if user is a remember-me user then there is no way to capture 'location' parameter because there won't be a login prompt. In case of remember-me feature spring stores only username in cookie. And for remember-me login it then retrieves that username from cookie and passes it to 'loadUserByUsername' call to load user from DB. So, in my case, for remember-me users, since 'location' is null query to load user fails.
 
I wanted to know if there is a way to override the default spring behavior and store 'location' in cookie along with username and then pass location and username to 'loadUserByUsername' in PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie().
Please see my code below for reference,

CustomAuthenticationFilter.java :-

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        final Long locationId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("locations"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("LOCATION_ID", locationId);

        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response); 
    } 
}
```

SecurityConfig.java:-

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    AccessDeniedExceptionHandler accessDeniedExceptionHandler;

    @Bean
    public CustomInvalidSessionStrategy invalidSessionStrategy() {
        return new CustomInvalidSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/secured/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
//      .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
        .permitAll()
        .and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedExceptionHandler);

        http.addFilterBefore(customAuthenticationFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(rememberMeAuthenticationFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() {
        AuthenticationManager manager = null;
        try {
            manager = super.authenticationManagerBean();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return manager;
    }


    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        handler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        handler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error");
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter () {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter filter= new  CustomAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","POST"));
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        filter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        filter.setRememberMeServices(persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rememberMeAuthenticationFilter() {
        RememberMeAuthenticationFilter filter = new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setRememberMeServices(persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices service = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember_me_key", userDetailsService, persistentTokenRepository());
        service.setCookieName("remember_me");
        service.setTokenValiditySeconds(864000);
        return service;
    }

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepositoryImpl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem! Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Extend class PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices and override its method as follow

```
  @Override    
    processAutoLoginCookie(String[] cookieTokens,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
   super.processAutoLoginCookie(cookieTokens,request,response); // do not provide any implementation to loadUserByUsername() in your CustomUserDetail and add one more method loadUserbyUsenameAndLocation(username, location);
   String location = request.getSession().getAttribute("LOCATION_ID");
   return ((customeUserDetailsService)userDetailsService).loadUserbyUsenameAndLocation(username, location)
}
```

Comment: Hi Bhushan, 'location' will be available only in case user is logging-in using login page. Because we are capturing location on login page and then putting it in session in CustomAuthenticationFilter. As opposed to this, remember-me login will come into picture when session has expired and user is trying to access the application. And hence no location will be available in session to be used in processAutoLoginCookie() method. Somehow i will have to find a way to store location in persistent_logins table and get that location in processAutoLoginCookie method.

Comment: persistent_logins is the table used by spring to store remember-me tokens and to get user name based on the token received in cookie.

Comment: you can add it to cookies as well. when user logs in first time send location id in cookies. You can retrieve cookies from request.