# Why spring makes it so hard to use additional login parameters with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In a spring mvc application i need to capture an additional 'location' parameter on login screen and use it for authentication in addition to username. I came across few approaches suggested to achieve this but none of it is straight forward and involves extending and/or implementing number of spring classes and interfaces. 
I somehow achieved it by extending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and by retrieving and putting location parameter in session.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        final Long locationId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("locations"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("LOCATION_ID", locationId);

        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response); 
    } 
}
```

This approach seems like a hack and doesn't seem too elegant. On top of that, now since i am using a custom AuthenticationFilter i have to manually configure this filter by injecting number of dependencies.

```
@Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter () {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter filter= new  CustomAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","POST"));
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        filter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        filter.setRememberMeServices(persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices());
        return filter;
    }
```

Eventually, capturing location and using it in authentication works but then it creates new issues if i want to use remember-me feature. I explained the problem here [Spring remember-me with extra login parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570818/spring-remember-me-with-extra-login-parameter). 
Using extra login parameters must be a common requirement. Spring framework known for being pluggable and extensible i wish there was a more user friendly way to use additional parameters. 
Can anyone please suggest me a better approach here to use extra parameter and get remember-me working as well. Thanks

Comment: It is extensible that is what you are currently doing, extending the non default behavior. If you need additional information in the remember-me section you need to implement a custom implementation as well.However your current solution is a hack, instead create a custom `Authentication` object which contains the needed information (username, pwd and location) instead of stuffing it in the session. This authentication is passed on to the other classes that need an authentication including the remember me stuff.

Comment: Hello Deinum, can you please provide some more details how this can be achieved using Authentication object. Do you mean something like extending WebAuthenticationDetails class? Even with WebAuthenticationDetails how can i get reference to it in UserService to retrieve location parameter? I cant get it from SecurityContextHolder because Authentication object get's populated there only after successful login. Secondly, in case of remember-me i will have to store and retrieve location either in cookie or persistent_login table. I am not sure how WebAuthenticationDetails can be of use there

Comment: No by creating your own `Authentication` instead of trying to bolt it onto the default `UsernamePasswordAuthentication` you have different requirements, then implement it properly instead of hacking something on top of sometihing else.

Answer (score 0):

The classes of spring security are really complicated.

Use AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter as your superclass.
Than you can return an Object instead of a String in
getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal
getPreAuthenticatedCredentials
there you read whatever you need from the HttpRequest and return an object that contains all the data you need (as you need it as principal or credential wherever location belongs.). Maybe you create a simple class for the return type.

Than you create a subclass of org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider
.In the method public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
you can access the objects you returned in AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter using authentication.getCredentials() and authentication.getPrincipal()
with this you create one or more new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role), one for each role the user has.Collect them in a List grantedAuthorities;
And finally create a 
Authentication auth=new new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(),authentication.getCredentials(),grantedAuthorities)
which you return.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your reply. But for passing extra login parameters finally what i did was to implement AuthenticationProvider and extend AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. As for remember-me feature i extended PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices and PersistentRememberMeToken and implemented PersistentTokenRepository.